# IE8 Render Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, internet-explorer-8

Why doesn't this document render in IE8 ??

http://arabiannights.thestagingurl.com/

Comment: It works if you enable IE7 mode or IE8 compatibility mode. Must be a browser quirk somewhere.

Comment: Works in IE7 (Compatibility View)

Comment: XHTML doctype, but it doesn't validate. Maybe that's what tips IE8 off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On ~line 55, if I change the last line of this:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
    .sf-contener {position: absolute; left: 0;}
    #right_column #cart_block .block_content a {position: relative; padding-top: 38px; top: -15px}
</style>
<! [endif] -->
```

to this:

```
<![endif]-->
```

Somehow the malformed IE conditional close comment was stopping the rest of the page from being parsed.